# SwipeGesture not working as i want to swipe from one activity to another

Tags: android

I want to swipe from one activity to another without using Viewpager and i want to use only SwipeGesture i have written the code but my screen is not sliding so anyone can tell me whats wrong with the code ?
here is my code:

```
public class Ashtakoota extends AbstractActivity implements IAPICallback,View.OnClickListener {

    private LinearLayout lnrAsht;

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_ashtakoota,mFrameLayout);


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        lnrAsht = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lnrAsht);


        lnrAsht.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };


    }



    private class SwipeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
        private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(Ashtakoota.this, "Gesture Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                float diffAbs = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());
                float diff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();

                if (diffAbs > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;

                // Left swipe
                if (diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    onLeftSwipe();
                }
                // Right swipe
                else if (-diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    onRightSwipe();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Home", "Error on gestures");
            }
            return false;
        }


    }

    private void onLeftSwipe() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,BasicAstro.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void onRightSwipe() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MatchManglik.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btn_match_ashtakootback:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,BasicAstro.class);
                startActivity(intent);}break;

            case R.id.btn_match_ashtakootnext:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,MatchManglik.class);
                startActivity(intent);}break;
        }
    }

    private boolean setImage(int value1,int value2){


        if (value1 == value2)
            return true;
        else if (value2 >=value1/2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```